# Grid not working in Bones theme

Tags: html, css, grid, menuitem

I'm using Bones theme from Themble, which includes a grid system in it's style. I have tried to implement it in the header for my menu items so that they will size down into icons in mobile size and show the full menu in desktop screens.

The problem is that I can't get the grid to work, all the menu items float next to each other, on all screen sizes. The divs 'menubar' is only as big as the icon.

The grid is working on other areas, such as the sidebars and content areas. I'm not really familiar with responsive columns so hopefully it's obvious to some of the pros here.

Also, so you know, I'm working locally with  koala, a processor for the Sass.

**Header**

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

    <div id="container">

        <header class="header" role="banner">

            <div id="inner-header" class="wrap ">


                    <div id="logo" class="menubar m1of5 t1of5 d2of6 cf">
                        <a  href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><img src="/home_icon.png">homepage</a>
                    </div>

                    <div id="menu-icon" class="menubar m1of5 t1of5 d1of6 cf">
                        <a  href="#"><img src="/icon.png"/></a>
                    </div>

                    <div id="menu-icon" class="menubar m1of5 t1of5 d1of6 cf">
                        <a  href="#"><img src="/icon.png"/></a>
                    </div>

                    <div id="menu-icon" class="menubar m1of5 t1of5 d1of6 cf">
                        <a  href="#"><img src="/icon.png"/></a>
                    </div>

                    <div id="menu-icon" class="menubar m1of5 t1of5 d1of6 last-col cf">
                        <a href="#"><img src="/icon.png"/></a>
                    </div>

                </div>

        </header>
```

**Grid**

```
@mixin grid-col {
 float: left;
 padding-right: 0.75em;
}

// the last column
.last-col {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {

.m-all {
 @include grid-col;
 width: 100%;
 padding-right: 0;
}

.m-1of5 {
 @include grid-col;
 width: 20%;
}

}
And on and on for other sizes and screens.
```

**Style**

```
This is the mobile styling....

.header {
width:100%;
position: fixed;
background-color: $white;
border-bottom: 2px solid $border-color;
}

.menubar {
 float: left;
 }

#logo {
 font-size: 0px;
 a {
 text-decoration: none;
   }
  }

#menu-icon {
 background-color: $light;
 border-radius: 4px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="logo" class="menubar m1of5 t1of5 d2of6 cf">
    <a  href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><img src="/home_icon.png">homepage</a>
</div>
```

Your class names should be hyphenated:

```
<div id="logo" class="menubar m-1of5 t-1of5 d-2of6 cf">
    <a  href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><img src="/home_icon.png">homepage</a>
</div>
```